# GetPropertyAsync freeze

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

Using puppeteer sharp I load a page and try to read the value of an attribute.
Html page:

```html
<body>
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGOD" alt="Red dot" />
 <a href="#" id="bottle">
```

I use this:

```
string awaitXPath = "//img[contains(@src, 'data:image/png;base64')][1]";
var element = await _page.WaitForXPathAsync(awaitXPath, new PuppeteerSharp.WaitForSelectorOptions() { Timeout = 5000 });
string strBase64 = await element.GetPropertyAsync("src").Result.JsonValueAsync<string>();
```

which is working OK for some cases, but sometimes it happens that my execution freeze when I try to GetPropertyAsync. There is a way to add a timeout to GetPropertyAsync? or maybe somebody has another idea to get @src attribute's value.

Thank you.

Comment: You are using `.Result`. `.Result` is blocking, you should use await all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use var strBase64 = await (await element.GetPropertyAsync("src")).JsonValueAsync();